# Prove $p \times(1 - p)^n$ is a probability function

Tags: probability

$p \times (1 - p)^n$ where $p$ is the probability an event will happen after $n$ number of failure attempts.

I know I have to show that the sum of the probabilities of all possible events equals one. How do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll want to look up the geometric series.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
For all $|a|<1$:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty {a^i}=\frac 1{1-a}
$$